# Matplotlib animation.FuncAnimation: Custom frame generator only yields once

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm encountering a strange problem with the matplotlib animation. I'm trying to create a animated bar plot using the following code:

```
import os, time
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.path as path
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import blackxample

FILE_PREFIX = "cell-isotohyper"
FILE_SUFFIX = ".tif"
FILE_PATH   = "./example-video"
XCUT = (91, 91+266)
YCUT = (646, 646+252)

LIMIT = 100
OFFSET = 0

Y_SCALE = 3000
NUM_OF_BINS = 37

BAR_WIDTH = 1.0
BAR_COLOR = 'b'
RANGE = range(0, NUM_OF_BINS//2+1)

def animate(i, fig, ax, bars):
    # = np.random.randn(1000)
    print(len(i))
    for a in RANGE:
        bars[a].set_height(i[a])
    return (fig, ax, bars)

def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_ylim(0, Y_SCALE)
    ax.set_xlim(0, NUM_OF_BINS//2+1)

    bars = ax.bar(np.arange(NUM_OF_BINS), [i for i in range(NUM_OF_BINS)], BAR_WIDTH, color=BAR_COLOR)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, xframes, fargs = (fig, ax, bars), interval=500)
    plt.show()
```

This code snippet works completely fine if I'm using randomly generated data or constant via:

```
def xframes():
    i = 0
    while i < 100:
        yield [2312.7094266223335, 27.238786592368257, 75.252063484372513, 13.678304922077643, 11.879804374653929, 21.900570139020687, 2.930771773796323, 11.945594479736741, 10.88517941461987, 4.4176609254771506, 4.1075871395528338, 1.248363771876285, 1.4798157379442216, 3.5285036346353564, 3.2583080973651732, 3.4640042567344267, 3.130503535456981, 0.67334205875304676, 0.71393606581800562]
        #yield np.histogram(np.random.randn(1000), NUM_OF_BINS//2 + 1)[0]
        i+=1
```

Using the function, aframes, instead, does only yield the first item if it is used together animation.FuncAnimation(). If aframe is iterated manually, however, **the generator works completely fine**.

```
def aframes():
    list_of_files = []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(FILE_PATH):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.startswith(FILE_PREFIX) and filename.endswith(FILE_SUFFIX):
                list_of_files.append(os.path.join(FILE_PATH, filename))

    # Open every picture - in every file
    count = 0
    imagecount = 0
    framecount = 0
    skipped = 0
    for file in list_of_files:
        framecount = 0
        a = Image.open(file)
        for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(a):
            if count > OFFSET and count <= OFFSET+LIMIT:
                # Cut image beforehand - probably faster
                frame = frame.crop((XCUT[0], YCUT[0], XCUT[1], YCUT[1]))
                # Load image intro Matrix
                imageMatrix = blackxample.Matrix.fromPillow(frame)
                try:
                    imageMatrix.findContour()
                    imageMatrix.calculateCentroid()
                    imageMatrix.transform(NUM_OF_BINS)
                    #yield imageMatrix.getTransform()
                    yield [2312.7094266223335, 27.238786592368257, 75.252063484372513, 13.678304922077643, 11.879804374653929, 21.900570139020687, 2.930771773796323, 11.945594479736741, 10.88517941461987, 4.4176609254771506, 4.1075871395528338, 1.248363771876285, 1.4798157379442216, 3.5285036346353564, 3.2583080973651732, 3.4640042567344267, 3.130503535456981, 0.67334205875304676, 0.71393606581800562]
                except blackxample.NoConvergenceError:
                    skipped+=1
            print("[", count ,"] done")

            framecount+=1
            count+=1
        imagecount+=1

# Test for frame iterator - works fine
#for i in _frames():
#    print(i)
```

**Does someone has a clue what and why is happening? How can I fix it?**

The generator also runs as expected if the three imageMatrix-lines inside the try-block are commented out which suggests that there is an error inside imageMatrix.findContour(). But what am I looking for? findContour doesn't do anything weird

Comment: I think you should be passing `animate(..., aframes(), ...)`  not `animate(..., aframes, ...)`

Comment: @tcaswell No, this doesn't work - animation.animate() treats a generator object as a sequence and tries to determine it's length with len() - which is not possible on a generator sequence and quits with a TypeError. This is the case for both aframes() and xframes().

Comment: @tcaswell I retract my statement - using a newer version of matplotlib indeed allows a generator to be passed directly. It does, however, not change the outcome, the function aframes() yields only once with animate, while xframes() does as much as I want it to. aframes() still works if it is iterated directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not found any solutions regarding this problem, I've decided to save the result of aframes() in a file, then reading and animating it seperatly which works flawlessly without adjusting the animation code.